# Retrive all data which is match from foreign key in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I am having trouble fetching data from another table. It works but I only get one row for one of the relationships and I want to get all related rows with the same foreign key.

Here is my code:

**controller**

```
$reply_message = FamilyMessage::with('communitymessages')
    ->where('resident_id', $request->resident_id)
    ->where('id', $request->id)
    ->latest('id')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

---

and I got this answer:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "id" => 176
    "community_id" => 25
    "resident_id" => 4515
    "name" => "romil"
    "message" => "test 1"
    "status" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:27:39"
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-21 05:28:51"
    "communitymessages" => array:10 [▼
      "id" => 21
      "user_id" => 3
      "resident_id" => 4515
      "community_id" => 25
      "family_message_id" => 176
      "name" => " romil "
      "reply_msg" => "reply test 1"
      "status" => 0
      "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
      "updated_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
    ]
  ]
]
```

---

see `communitymessages` only get 1 row, but I want all rows where store same forign key.

I want answer like this

```
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "id" => 176
    "community_id" => 25
    "resident_id" => 4515
    "name" => "romil"
    "message" => "test 1"
    "status" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:27:39"
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-21 05:28:51"
    "communitymessages" => array:10 [▼
      "id" => 21
      "user_id" => 3
      "resident_id" => 4515
      "community_id" => 25
      "family_message_id" => 176
      "name" => " romil "
      "reply_msg" => "reply test 1"
      "status" => 0
      "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
      "updated_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
    ],
    "communitymessages" => array:10 [▼
      "id" => 22
      "user_id" => 3
      "resident_id" => 4515
      "community_id" => 25
      "family_message_id" => 176
      "name" => " romil "
      "reply_msg" => "reply test 2"
      "status" => 0
      "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
      "updated_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
    ],
    "communitymessages" => array:10 [▼
      "id" => 23
      "user_id" => 3
      "resident_id" => 4515
      "community_id" => 25
      "family_message_id" => 176
      "name" => " romil "
      "reply_msg" => "reply test 3"
      "status" => 0
      "created_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
      "updated_at" => "2020-01-20 11:28:15"
    ]

  ]
]
```

These are the relationships:

```
public function communitymessages() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\CommunityMessage', 'family_message_id'); 
}
```

```
public function familymessages() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\FamilyMessage','family_message_id'); 
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the relationship code for `communitymessages` in your `FamilyMessage` model.

Comment: public function communitymessages() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CommunityMessage', 'family_message_id');
    }

Comment: public function familymessages() {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\FamilyMessage','family_message_id');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're only getting one row is because you're telling Eloquent that it should only have one row (`hasOne`).

To retrieve all the related rows you want to update your relationship from `hasOne` to a `hasMany`:

```
public function communitymessages()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommunityMessage', 'family_message_id'); 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, it worked properly as i want.

Comment: @romil Glad I could help!

Comment: hi can you please help me for this   https://stackoverflow.com/q/60088272/11469255